# Xamarin Forms ContentView Binding Issue

Tags: xamarin.forms

#### Description

Xamarin Forms does not bind to ContentView properties as expected.

**Goal**

Reuse visual elements whenever possible to maintain consistent style and decrease duplicate code.

**Expected**

BindableProperty in the ContentView should be set with `MyText="{Binding Text}"` and be rendered as shown here:

[image]

**Actual**

The BindableProperty is not set as expected and is rendered as shown here:

[image]

**Environment**

- Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1560
- Issue appears on iOS and Android

#### Code

Solution code has been uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/robertkemp/so-xf-binding).

#### ItemsPage.xaml

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Item">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <!-- ItemsPage Binding -->
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" />

                <!-- ContentView Static Text-->
                <cv:MyContentView Grid.Column="1" MyText="Text!" />

                <!-- ContentView Binding -->
                <cv:MyContentView Grid.Column="2" MyText="{Binding Text}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

#### MyContentView.xaml

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding MyText}" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" />
```

#### MyContentView.xaml.cs

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyText), typeof(string), typeof(MyContentView),
    default(string), propertyChanged: MyTextChanged);
private static void MyTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    // Called 7 times on first load (there are only 5 items in the MockDataStore).
    // Called 1 time when performing a RefreshView/LoadItemsCommand.
    Debug.WriteLine($"MyTextChanged, oldValue: {oldValue}, newValue: {newValue}");
    ((MyContentView)bindable).MyTextChanged((string)oldValue, (string)newValue);
}
private void MyTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    MyText = newValue;
}
public string MyText
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
    }
    private set
    {
        SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Application Output

```
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
MyTextChanged, oldValue: , newValue: Text!
```

Comment: `Text="{Binding MyText}"` - you need to specify a source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove binding context in constructor

```
public MyContentView()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //BindingContext = this;
}
```

Add Source to your binding

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="BindingIssue.ContentViews.MyContentView"
    x:Name="myContentView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Label Text="{Binding MyText,Source={x:Reference myContentView}}" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White"/>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

[Voila!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rm3B.png)

Comment: @Robert if you could edit your question to content view binding instead of collection view that would help everyone.

Comment: At the time I created the question I thought the issue was specific to binding in a CollectionView.  I updated the question title.